# "Class mixed does not exist" with only one array param in the body in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, api

I have a custom Magento 2 PUT request that looks like:

```
<route method="PUT" url="/V1/items">
    <service class="Vendor\Items\Api\ItemsManagementInterface" method="replaceItems" />
        <resources>
            <resource ref="self" />
    </resources>
 </route>
```

Class interface:

```
/**
 * Description
 *
 * @param mixed $items
 * @return string
 */
public function replaceItems($items);
```

The request works with this JSON body payload:

```
{
  "items": [
    "url1",
    "url2"
  ],
  randomParam: true
}
```

Instead, an error is trown if the payload is just:

```
{
  "items": [
    "url1",
    "url2"
  ]
}
```

The full error returned from Magento REST Api:

> {
>           "message": "Class mixed does not exist",
>           "code": -1,
>           "trace": "#0 vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/MethodsMap.php(155): ReflectionClass->__construct('mixed')
>   #1 vendor/magento/framework/Reflection/MethodsMap.php(106): Magento\Framework\Reflection\MethodsMap->getMethodMapViaReflection('mixed')
>   #2 vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/ParamsOverrider.php(203): Magento\Framework\Reflection\MethodsMap->getMethodsMap('mixed')
>   #3 vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/ParamsOverrider.php(147): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\ParamsOverrider->isPropertyDeclaredInDataObject('GV\\Products\\Api...', 'replaceItems...', 'items')
>   #4 vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest/InputParamsResolver.php(93): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\ParamsOverrider->overrideRequestBodyIdWithPathParam(Array, Array, 'Vendor\\Items\\Api...', 'replaceItems...')
>   #5 vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(322): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\InputParamsResolver->resolve()
>   #6 vendor/magento/module-webapi/Controller/Rest.php(239): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->processApiRequest()
>   #7 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>   #8 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callParent('dispatch', Array)
>   #9 vendor/magento/framework/Interception/Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>   #10 generated/code/Magento/Webapi/Controller/Rest/Interceptor.php(39): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->___callPlugins('dispatch', Array, Array)
>   #11 vendor/magento/framework/App/Http.php(135): Magento\Webapi\Controller\Rest\Interceptor->dispatch(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http))
>   #12 generated/code/Magento/Framework/App/Http/Interceptor.php(24): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
>   #13 vendor/magento/framework/App/Bootstrap.php(256): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
>   #14 index.php(39): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
>   #15 {main}"
>       }

I have already recompiled the DI and flushed the cache.

Also tried in the class interface: `mixed[]`, `string[]`, etc..

---

**Goal:** being able to make a request passing only a single array parameter, without the need to also pass a second param.

Comment: have you tried the solution which is in answer ?

Answer (score 1):

**Class interface:**

```
/**
 * Description
 *
 * @param string[] $items
 * @return array
 */
public function replaceItems($items);
```

**Valid scalar types** include: `mixed` (or anyType), `bool` (or boolean), `str` (or string), `integer` (or int), `float`, and `double`

Any parameters or return values of type array can be denoted by following any of the previous types by an empty set of square brackets []

```
@return array|int|string|bool|float Scalar or array of scalars
```

**Reference**

> https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/extension-dev-guide/service-contracts/service-to-web-service.html

Comment: Which one should I use for a single Array body input? I already tried string[] it  does not work

Comment: Are you sure your o/p will array ?

Comment: This is the request body, yes it is an array of strings:

`{
  "items": [
    "url1",
    "url2"
  ]
}`

Comment: Have you checked my updated answer ?

Comment: I am using this  
$response = ['success' => 'true'];
return $resultJson->setData($response);
but i got same error.

Comment: Please elaborate the case with your code.

Comment: @AdityaShah Checked your updated answer. Sorry but actually it does not provides anything more than already known. Using *string[]* as class and *array* as return, does not works, the error is the same. I still think that this is a Magento 2.2 bug

Answer (score 1):

In the API function docs **DO NOT** use any of the following.

```
@param mixed
@param mixed[]
@return mixed
@return mixed[]
```